# RAII classes for Brew

Tags: brew-framework, brewmp

Writing code in Brew when local interfaces are being used in it can be repetitive and error prone to make it robust, i.e.:

```
Foo()
{
ISomeInterface* interface = NULL;
int err = ISHELL_Createnstance(…,...,&interface);

err = somethingThatCanFail();
if (AEE_SUCCESS != err)
    ISomeInterface_Release(interface);

err = somethingElseThatCanFail()
if (AEE_SUCCESS != err)
    ISomeInterface_Release(interface);

etc....
```

It would be quick to write an RAII class to automatically release the interface on exit from the function, but it would be specific to a particular interface (it would of course call ISomeInterface_Release in its destructor)

Is there any way of making a generic RAII class that can be used for interfaces of different types? i.e. is there a generic Release function that could be called in the RAII instead of the interface specific release, or some other mechanism?

--- Edit ----
Apologies, I originally added the C++ and RAII tags to this posting which I've now removed.
As the answer requires Brew knowledge not C++ knowledge.
Thanks to the people who took the time to answer, I should have added more info to begin with and not added those additional tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RAII class that calls a specified function in destructor may look like this:

```
template<typename T, void (*onRelease)(T)>
class scope_destroyer {
    T m_data;

public:
    scope_destroyer(T const &data) 
        : m_data(data)
    {}

    ~scope_destroyer() { onRelease(m_data); }

    //...
};
```

Then you just pass a type `T` (e.g. a `Foo*`) and a function that can be called with a single parameter of type `T` and releases the object.

```
scope_destroyer<Foo, &ISomeInterface_Release> foo(CreateFoo());
```

Comment: Thanks, but after having a closer look into the brew side of things, its not as simple as it being a function call. There's a bunch of #defines which eventually reduces down to the following (simplyfied a bit): (TypeName##Vtbl)->Release(pointer).  Using a template for TypeName doesn't work due to the ## stringization preprocessing (the result is a stringization of T##Vtbl, not the actual typename as required)

Answer (score 3):

`shared_ptr` does what you ask for:

```
ISomeInterface* interface = NULL;
int err = ISHELL_Createnstance(…,...,&interface);
std::shared_ptr<ISomeInterface*> pointer(interface, ISomeInterface_Release);
```

Reference: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#constructors

---

**EDIT** Here is a sample:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory>

int main(int ac, char **av) {
  std::shared_ptr<FILE> file(fopen("/etc/passwd", "r"), fclose);
  int i;
  while( (i = fgetc(file.get())) != EOF)
    putchar(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but Brew doesn't support std/shared_ptr

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of help. Thanks for updating the tags.